# how to retrieve all videos stored in iphone camera roll

Tags: iphone

I am using following code to choose image from camera role

```
 picker= [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
//picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourc

//[self addSubview:imagePickerController.view];
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

but this shows only images , but i want to show all videos present in camera role ,
how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just wanting to allow UIImagePickerController to select videos instead of photos, it's easy: just assign an array containing kUTTypeMovie to the picker's `mediaTypes` property:

```
picker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];
```

If you want videos and photos, include both kUTTypeMovie and kUTTypeImage:

```
picker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, (NSString *)kUTTypeImage, nil];
```

If you want to actually retrieve these movies, and you're targeting iOS 4.0 and above, you can use [ALAssetsLibrary](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to get the list without user intervention.

Comment: @mobile.jugnu: It's in the MobileCoreServices framework. Add that framework to your project if it isn't already included, and then `#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>`.